# How to correct icon alignment for an xe:toolBarButton in the actionFacet of the Page Heading?

Tags: dojo, xpages, xpages-extlib, dojox.mobile

The following image shows proper alignment for the mblDomButtonWhitePlus icon for the xe:toolBarButton on the left, but not so good on the right in the xe:djxmHeading.

[image]

Here is the source for the Page Heading control:

```
    <xe:djxmHeading id="djxmHeading1" label="appPage1">
            <xe:toolBarButton id="toolBarButton3" moveTo="appPage2">
                <xe:this.dojoAttributes>
                    <xp:dojoAttribute name="icon" value="mblDomButtonWhitePlus">
                    </xp:dojoAttribute>
                </xe:this.dojoAttributes>
            </xe:toolBarButton>
            <xp:this.facets>
                <xe:toolBarButton id="toolBarButton4" moveTo="appPage3"
                    xp:key="actionFacet">
                    <xe:this.dojoAttributes>
                        <xp:dojoAttribute name="icon" value="mblDomButtonWhitePlus">
                        </xp:dojoAttribute>
                    </xe:this.dojoAttributes>
                </xe:toolBarButton>
            </xp:this.facets>
        </xe:djxmHeading>
```

Any ideas on how to correct the icon alignment for the xe:toolBarButton in the actionFacet of the Page Heading?

Comment: I try to reproduce your problem, but I can't find xe:toolbarbutton in my environment (853).
which version you are using?

Comment: the xe: controls are Extension Library controls, available for 8.5.3 from openNTF.org or natively in release 9

Comment: Thanks, I just have the 853 nativ extlib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

override *.mblHeadingActionFacet div {top: 4px;}*  will drop the plus sign in place... you may need to change *top* pixels value based on how your div's are positioned (relative for example).